# Disable HTML content for IE users

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser, web

I'm wanting to create (or use existing) code that will disable a pages content for IE users.

This HTML page should only be available to Google Chrome and Firefox users.

Any ideas on where I should start at, or if you know of any code like this that already exists? I'm a novice to programming and need a headstart, but I'm willing to program my own code if someone can push me in the right direction.

Comment: what type of content?

Comment: terrible idea, why do you want to do it?

Comment: At the top of the page, php can parse the browser name and if it contains MSIE, Internet Explorer, or Trident, it can exit or die.

Comment: I agree that this would typically be a terrible idea... But if you want to make it happen... Try what I posted below...

Comment: Define "disable."  If you just hide content that's already been delivered to the client using styling then the users can still interact with it if they want to.  Is this supposed to be some kind of preventive measure for something?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's up to you but if you were to achieve this via `serverside`, you're best to do it using `.htaccess` - but that's just "me". ;-)

Comment: you really need to explain why you would want to alienate 20%+ of all web users

Comment: All methods are not 100% reliable, so you'd better ask user: "Are you using IE?" 1. "Hmmm, yes" - "Get off my site" 2. "No!" - "Welcome!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your head section:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-styles.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then in that stylesheet make it:

```
body {
display: none;
}
```

Additionally, add the following code to your `<head>` to ensure that later versions of IE will read the conditional comments.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

Comment: Naturally, you can make the stylesheet whatever you want it to be, but this will simply make the page not display to IE users.

Comment: You can also just put a `<style>` block in the conditional itself rather than linking off to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function({
   jQuery.each( jQuery.browser, function( i, val ) {
         if ( $.browser.webkit || $.browser.mozilla ) {
           alert( "Render HTML!" );
         }
   });
}));
```

Or with PHP function get_browser()
http://www.php.net/get_browser

Comment: JS can be disabled. Serverside is the way to go. Least, that's how I would go about it, instead of relying on any type of client-side method.

Comment: This property was removed from jQuery 1.9 [proof](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)!

Comment: It's true this property was removed, but it will work on 1.3 version

Comment: How do you know that OP uses jQuery 1.3?

Comment: How do you know is not?, however, it can be if not the best, a possible solution

Comment: solution based on deprecated and non-working methods is never a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Without the CSS or JavaScript, I guess this is the best solution.

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
    <body>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </body>
<!--[endif]-->
```

Surround the `<body>` tags with `IF !IE` conditional comments.

Comment: Just to add though that [conditional comments no longer work for IE 10+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @kei Chances are IE 10+ will display things correctly, thankfully.

Comment: I guess Microsoft didn't like that or could no longer afford being blocked. (Now, that's news to me) Good to know this type of information. @kei

Comment: Good call. I actually edited my answer to this question to reflect compliance for this point. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `.htaccess` on your server, you can use this `server-side` (redirection) method.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*MSIE.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ie.php
# RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/ie.php
```